# drawable rotating only once

Tags: android, progress-bar, fresco

I've created custom progressbar to be displayed in Fresco SimpleDraweeView while loading an image from network. I want the progressbar to be indeterminate 
Progressbar is rotating only once and then drawable is just staying stationary. Here is the xml code for progressbar.

custom_progress_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">

    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="15"
        android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="24dip" android:height="24dip" />

        <gradient
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#00FFFFFF"
            android:centerColor="#97A4001D"
            android:centerY="0.50"
            android:endColor="#FFA4001D" />

    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Fresco SimpleDraweeView used in another layout.

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/full_view_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    fresco:failureImage="@drawable/ic_broken_image_black_24dp"
                    fresco:failureImageScaleType="centerInside"
                    android:background="@color/com_facebook_button_border_color_focused"
                    fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"
                    fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="centerInside"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"`
Adding the above attribute to SimpleDraweeView saved my day.

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/video_thumbnail"
                app:layout_aspectRatio="145%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
                fresco:failureImage="@drawable/ic_broken_image_black_24dp"
                fresco:failureImageScaleType="centerInside"
                android:background="@color/com_facebook_button_border_color_focused"
                fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/crafter_progress_bar"
                fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"
                fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="centerInside"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `android:repeatCount="infinite"` to your `custom_progress_bar.xml` under `rotate`

Comment: RepeatCount worked for progressBar drawable. But it didn't work with Fresco SimpleDraweeView. After going through API documentation `fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"` this attribute saved my day.